# Mock ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext() call using when in mockito .How can i do that?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito, springmockito

I am trying to mock ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext() call in when using mockito but its fails to mock.

```
  //here is my source code            
  @Mock
  org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

//test Case Body
 try (MockedStatic<ContextLoader> dummy = Mockito.mockStatic(ContextLoader.class)) {
                    
AnswerInfo answerInfo = Mockito.mock(AnswerInfo.class);
                    
TranDescScoreInfo descScoreInfo2 = Mockito.mock(TranDescScoreInfo.class);
                    
when(ctx.getBean("answerInfo")).thenReturn(answerInfo);
when(ctx.getBean("tranDescScoreInfo")).thenReturn(descScoreInfo2);
                    
dummy.when(() -> ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()).thenReturn(webApplicationContext);
                    
//ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext() getting null I dont why it getting null.
                            
        }

//Below Code is my business logic  
 ApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
 AnswerInfo answerInfo = (AnswerInfo) ctx.getBean("answerInfo");
 tranDescScoreInfo = (TranDescScoreInfo) ctx.getBean("tranDescScoreInfo");
```

//    ctx.getBean  getting null because i am not getting mock call here as expected
Note: I don't want to change my business logic

Comment: Are you using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` or any annotation to initialize the mockito annotations?

Comment: @Marco  I am using JUnit 5. I Used closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the code inside the try. I hope this works for you:

```
class UserTest {
    @Mock
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @BeforeEach
     void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
     void test() {

//test Case Body
        try (MockedStatic<ContextLoader> dummy = Mockito.mockStatic(ContextLoader.class)) {
            Mockito.when(webApplicationContext.getBean("answerInfo")).thenReturn(new String());
            dummy.when(ContextLoader::getCurrentWebApplicationContext).thenReturn(webApplicationContext);
            //Below Code is my business logic
            ApplicationContext ctx = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
            assertNotNull( ctx.getBean("answerInfo"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this after some RnD it's working for me 
The below code is worked for me:

@Mock
static ServletContext servletContext;

@Mock
ContextLoader contextLoader;

@Mock
org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;

private AutoCloseable closeable;

@BeforeAll
static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    MockServletContext msc = new MockServletContext();
    msc.addInitParameter(ContextLoader.CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM, "/test/config/spring/SpringBeansTest.xml");

    ServletContextListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener();
    ServletContextEvent event = new ServletContextEvent(msc);
    listener.contextInitialized(event);
}

@AfterAll
static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {

}

@BeforeEach
void setUp() throws Exception {

    closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    Mockito.doReturn(Random.class).when(ctx).getBean(Mockito.anyString());

    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws Exception {
    closeable.close();
    closeable = null;
}
//test case body
try (MockedStatic<ContextLoader> dummy = Mockito.mockStatic(ContextLoader.class)) {
dummy.when(() -> ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()).thenReturn(webApplicationContext);
}
```